# Can't display polygon generated from rgdal in shiny-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, shiny, rgdal

I want to generate a choropleth map using leaflet-shiny with my own geojson file. The whole data and r code can be accessed from [here](https://gist.github.com/MengyingLi/6b7c34b64931ae4fd65e/). I don't understand why the map does not show up but without no error message.

Comment: when I copie/paste your geojson file in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) it seems malformed

Comment: @delaye thank you so much for the reply! I think the problem might be that I add a `;` in the end for the purpose of displaying it in `leaflet.js` Thanks!